# Can't enable spacemacs' shell layer

Tags: shell, emacs, spacemacs

I'm trying to enable spacemacs' shell layer.  I'm doing so by uncommenting the:

```
  (shell :variables
        shell-default-height 30
        shell-default-position 'bottom)
```

Part in the `~/.spacemacs` file.

However, when opening Emacs, I get the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/amir/.emacs.d/init.el':
error: Required feature `xterm-color' was not provided
```

Any idea how to work around this? was not able to file the answer on the net.

Comment: Load (`require`) the expected library: the one that provides feature `xterm-color`. The library name is also probably `xterm-color.el`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For some reason the xterm-color package files were blank. Delete the directory ~/.emacs.d/elpa/xterm-color-INSERT-VERSION and restart spacemacs.

EDIT: You might need to delete ~/.emacs.d/elpa/shell-pop as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't remember what I was doing, but it finally ended up working.